# Pick random Card from a "strange" Deck (Java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a new card game in Java(didn't invent it, just have to), where the deck is kind of different from the traditional ones. Deck is made of 90 cards, divided this way: 13 orange cards, 13 white cards, 13 black cards, 13 blue cards, 13 grey cards, 13 purple cards and 12 jolly. All these cards are named "Political Cards".

I would like to represent the deck as an Array of 7 elements:

```
public class PoliticalDeck {
    private PoliticalCard[] deck; 

    public PoliticalDeck() {
        deck = new PoliticalCard[7]; 
    }

    //estrai una carta a caso
    public void pickRandomCard() {

    }
}
```

Could this be correct? How could I implement the card picking method?

Comment: Why would you want the deck split into 7 pieces?  You shouldn't need it to tell which "color" a card is; that should be part of PoliticalCard (whose definition you did not share).

Comment: Is the deck made up of 90 cards, or 7 cards?

Comment: what does your card class look like? It should encapsulate what it means to "be a card" - e.g. card are black, blue, gray, purple, or "jolly", and I assume have a value (1-13). Create 90 of these card objects (use loops) and put them into your array. To pick at random, you might "shuffle" the array and then return the first card.

Comment: Please allow me to explain better: "Political Cards" have just a Color, they don't have any other identifiers. Should I include and "int ID" as identifier? could this be ok?

Answer (score 1):

Put the cards in a List or a Deque (a double-ended queue), shuffle them with the Fisher-Yates shuffle, and deal them by removing them from the collection:

```
public enum Suit {
    ORANGE, WHITE, BLACK, BLUE, GREY, PURPLE, JOLLY;
}
```

Cards:

```
public class Card {
    private final Suit suit;
    private final int value;

    public Card(Suit suit, int value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() { return suit; }
    public int getValue() { return value; }
    @Override public String toString() { return value + " of " + suit; }
}
```

Deck:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Deck {
    private Deque<Card> deck;

    public Deck() {
        LinkedList<Card> cards = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            int limit = suit == Suit.JOLLY? 12 : 13;
            for (int value = 1; value <= limit; ++value) {
                cards.add(new Card(suit, value));
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
        deck = cards;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { return deck.isEmpty(); }
    public int remaining() { return deck.size(); }
    public Card deal() { return deck.remove(); }
}
```

This leaves out a number of features you might want for your game, such as dealing a hand of `n` cards at a time instead of dealing them one-by-one, reshuffling the deck (to shuffle with this, just create a new deck), the concept of a "discard" pile (don't know if your game has that), and decent `equals` and `hashCode` methods on `Card`. You may also want to have `Card` implement `Comparable<Card>`. Those are left as an exercise for the reader.